# Dark camera preview observed in 6.0.1 affdex-sdk

Tags: android, android-camera, affdex-sdk

I have integrated the Affectiva Android SDK. It is working as expected in Lollipop, but in Marshmallow phone a dark preview is observed. The camera application is working fine.

Is there any possibility to set the brightness to fix dark preview issue?

Comment: What is the source of the preview image?  The Detector::ImageListener::onImageResults callback?

Comment: Camera Streaming yes I am following the same options Camera Detector::ImageListener::onImageResults callback.The brightness of recording stream is very dull.

Comment: I have not seen this issue before.  If you can post a project that reproduces the issue to the Affectiva developer forum (http://discuss.affectiva.com/), we may be able to diagnose the cause.